# Extending the hamming distance on Sym$(X)$ to linear groups

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, symmetric-groups

I was reading of the hamming distance on the symmetry group of a finite set $X$. The distance was defined as follows: $$\text{d}^H (\sigma_1 , \sigma_2) = \frac{| { x \in X : \sigma_1(x) \neq \sigma_2(x) }|}{|X|}$$

where $\sigma_1 , \sigma_2 \in \text{Sym}(X)$. This definition gives us a way to measure the distance between two permutations of a finite set $X$. Now I was wondering if this definition can be extended to matrices. In particular, we know that $\phi: \text{Sym}(X) \to \text{GL}_{|X|}(\mathbb{Z}_2)$ is a faithful representation (Hence we can actually conclude that $\phi$ is a group isomorphism since $X$ is finite).

Hence is there a way to define $\text{d}^H (g_1 , g_2)$ where $g_1 , g_2 \in \text{GL}_{|X|}(\mathbb{Z}_2)$ such that this distance coincides with its hamming distance on the symmetry group?

Comment: There are many ways to extend this function to all of $GL_{|X|}(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$, so to narrow it down, you probably want to specify some other properties you want this extension to have. Anyway, here is one candidate which may or may not suit your needs: note that for two permutations $\sigma_{1}, \sigma_{2}$ in $S(X)$, for any $x \in X$ we have $\sigma_{1}(x) = \sigma_{2}(x)$ iff $x$ is a fixed point of $\sigma_{1}\sigma_{2}^{-1}$. In turn, it is easy to calculate the number of fixed points of the matrix representation of a permutation - just compute its trace. Hence, you can...

Comment: ...define the function $d \colon GL_{|X|}(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}) \times GL_{|X|}(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}) \to \mathbb{Q}$ by $d(g_{1}, g_{2}) = \operatorname{Tr}(g_{1}g_{2}^{-1})/|X|$. As argued by my first comment, this restricts to hamming distance on the embedded copy of $S(X)$.

Comment: Oops, a bunch of small errors: first, I should have written "iff $x$ is a fixed point of $\sigma_{2}^{-1}\sigma_{1}$", and I guess $d^{H}(\sigma_{1}, \sigma_{2})$ counts the elements of $X$ on which the two permutations *disagree*, namely $|X|-\operatorname{Tr}(\sigma_{2}^{-1}\sigma_{1})$. Anyway, in that case, you can take $d(g_{1}, g_{2}) = 1-(\operatorname{Tr}(g_{2}^{-1}g_{1})/|X|)$.

Comment: Question. How is the trace of a square matrix related to number of fixed points of a permutation? The only thing I can think of is that the trace of a matrix is the sum of its eigenvalues.

Comment: Also, since the field in question is $\mathbb{Z}_2$, would the trace of any of the matrices have to only be 0 or 1?

Comment: I am being glib about the whole $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ thing, and saying treat a $1 \in \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ as a $1$ in $\mathbb{Q}$, and likewise with $0$, so that the trace is just an ordinary natural number given by a sum of some number of ones. Anyway, if it makes you uncomfortable, there's no reason that the standard matrix representation of $S(X)$ has to take image in $GL_{|X|}(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$; it could just as well take values in $GL_{|X|}(\mathbb{Q})$, in which case there's no confusion.

Comment: That makes sense

Comment: As for your question about the relationship between the trace and the number of fixed points, I encourage you to try the example when $X = \{1, 2, 3\}$, so that $S(X) = S_{3}$, and see what is happening for each of the six matrices you get. You will see that you have a $1$ on the $n$th diagonal entry iff $n$ is a fixed point of your permutation.

Comment: After thinking about it for a bit I came to terms about the correlation between being fixed by a permutation and the trace of the representation of that permutation